# Bootstrap 4 Image not responsive and denying classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a image that I would like to disappear when on mobile, I tried many classes and none have any effect. And switch to only a row instead of the 2 columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown">OBRIGADO</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgfoot img-fluid mx-auto d-block d-sm-none d-md-block" src="storage/app/media/arrow-2.png" alt="" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1 class="text-right wow fadeInDown animated" style="margin-top: 60px;font-size: 85px;">PARTILHA COM ALGUEM</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up class logic:
You need to set image to d-none (for all views) then d-md-block (display from sizes MD up).

**TLDR:**
Remove those classes from img: d-block d-sm-none d-md-block
Add those classes to the img: d-none d-md-block

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown">OBRIGADO</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <img class="imgfoot img-fluid mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block col-sm-12  col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-right wow fadeInDown animated" style="margin-top: 60px;font-size: 85px;">PARTILHA COM ALGUEM</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, you need so set col-12 for image and hide text column with d-none but call it back d-md-block from md sizes up

Comment: Still the same, i thought it was my imgfoot class but no its ok just changes height and width of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-ls-6 col-xl-6">
      <img class="imgfoot img-fluid mx-auto d-block d-sm-none d-md-block" src="storage/app/media/arrow-2.png" alt="" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-ls-6 col-xl-6">
      <h1 class="text-right wow fadeInDown animated" style="margin-top: 60px;font-size: 85px;">PARTILHA COM ALGUEM</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

col-sm use for mobile portion. col-ls  & col-xl large scene like laptop & large monitor & default only col like col-12 is for all scene so just change it col-sm to col-xl & col-ls

Answer (score 0):

Change the **d-block** in the img tag to **d-none** and remove **d-sm-none**

**d-none** would set the image css display property to none starting from screen width of zero to infinity.

**d-md-block** would counteract the property set by **d-none** by changing display property of devices having minimum width of 768px to block.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints